# Query not checking one field properly

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a query that should check input order number, first name and post number and check if they match what is in the wordpress database, but the query always goes through no matter what post number I input, the code itself looks like this:

```
  // Taking the user input into variables
  $ordernumber = $_POST['ordernmbr'];
  $orderfirstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $orderpostnumber = $_POST['postnmbr'];
  $page = $_POST['page'];
  // Sanitizing
  $ordernumber = stripslashes_deep($ordernumber);
  $orderfirstname = stripslashes_deep($orderfirstname);
  $orderpostnumber = stripslashes_deep($orderpostnumber);

  // Query that searches for order data from db
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta
  WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key in ('_billing_first_name', '_billing_postcode')
  and meta_value in ('%s', '%d' )

  group by post_id", $ordernumber, $orderfirstname, $orderpostnumber);

  $res = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

What am I missing so that the post number would also be required to be correct

Comment: Does the query still work if your enter a wrong firstname and a wrong ordernumber? I don't fully understand your code and needs but `meta_value in ('%s', '%d')` evaluates to true if at least one of `$orderfirstname` or `$orderpostnumber` is true. Hence, it is always true if your have a valid `$orderfirstname`, independent from the entered number.

Comment: @Drudge That is exactly what I am baffled about, even though there's billing postcode and first name defined and asked in the query, it works only if first name and order number are right, but if postcode is wrong it doesn't care at all.